Setting `ulimit -l unlimited` for non-root user
I am playing with llama.cpp on OpenBSD-current. The program has a --mlock flag to force loading the model into physical memory (i.e. disable mmap). However, running as a non-root user gives warning: failed to mlock 730202112-byte buffer (after previously locking 0 bytes): Resource temporarily unavailable despite the system having 64GiB memory installed. I suspect this is a ulimit problem, since "Maximum size that may be locked into memory" is only 87381kB, and I cannot increase it as a non-root user.
$ ulimit -a
Maximum size of core files created                         (kB, -c) unlimited
Maximum size of a process’s data segment                   (kB, -d) 4194304
Maximum size of files created by the shell                 (kB, -f) unlimited
Maximum size that may be locked into memory                (kB, -l) 87381
Maximum resident set size                                  (kB, -m) 64901696
Maximum number of open file descriptors                        (-n) 128
Maximum stack size                                         (kB, -s) 8192
Maximum amount of CPU time in seconds                 (seconds, -t) unlimited
Maximum number of processes available to current user          (-u) 1310

$ ulimit -l unlimited
ulimit: Permission denied when changing resource of type 'Maximum size that may be locked into memory'

The obvious approach is to su - and ulimit -l unlimited, but then I have to run llama.cpp as root, which is probably not a good idea. How can I increase ulimit -l for a non-root user?

Try su - (or su or sudo -i or sudo -s), then ulimit -l unlimited, and then do su nalzok or sudo -s -unalzok.

ulimit is a shell builtin command which queries the kernel's get/setrlimit() syscalls. The calls, in turn, use the kernel's resource limiting mechanism, whose policy is set via login.conf(5).
Within /etc/login.conf, a set of capability classes is defined, and every user account on the system must be assigned to one of these classes (or default if not explicitly assigned). For each capability, here is what setrlimit(2) says:

A resource limit is specified as a soft limit and a hard limit.
When a
soft limit is exceeded a process may receive a signal (for example, if
the CPU time or file size is exceeded), but it will be allowed to
continue execution until it reaches the hard limit (or modifies its
resource limit).
[...]
Only the superuser may raise the maximum limits. Other users may only
alter [the limit] within the range from 0 to [the hard limit] or (irreversibly) lower [the hard limit].

Thus, even if you use ulimit -l unlimited as a non-root user, you will be capped to the hard limit for mlock, which is 256KB by default.
The solution will require you to modify /etc/login.conf (or create a /etc/login.conf.d/${class} file) to explicitly set a higher limit for the class of the user(s) who need it.
For example, if your user belongs to the staff class (which you can determine by examining /etc/master.passwd as a superuser), you can add the following line under the staff:\ entry in login.conf:
    :memorylocked-max=1024M:\
    :memorylocked-cur=1024M:\

Then log out and log back in.
